# How are these translations of "I had an exam yesterday" different?

Tags: grammar, particles

How would "I had an exam yesterday" be translated?

> きのうテストをありました。
>
> きのうテストをしました。

If both of the above are correct, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first sentence is almost grammatical.  It has one big problem, though: ある doesn't take a direct object (marked with を).  If you replaced it with が, it would be grammatical with the intended meaning:

> 昨日{きのう}テスト**が**ありました。

I think in this context you could also say 試験{しけん}:

> 昨日[試験]{しけん}**が**ありました。

Alternatively, you can use the verb 受{う}ける, saying you *took* a test rather than *had* a test:

> 昨日テスト**を**受{う}けました。

Notice the を here rather than が, because テスト is the direct object of 受けました.

Your second sentence is grammatical but テストをする wouldn't be my first choice to express having a test.  I think that phrase would be more likely if you were giving someone else a test than taking one yourself.

Comment: is うける the same meaning as もらいます？

Comment: @AhmedAbdelMoneimElket, the two verbs do not mean the same thing. もらう is to receive - for example to receive a present. うける is to take, with take a test being one of the more common uses.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a grammatical mistake. Your first sentence needs to use `が`, not `を`.

As for the difference, a literal translation should make it clear.

> きのうテストがありました.

This means, "there was a test yesterday."

> きのうテストをしました。

"Yesterday, (I) tested." Note this seems a little incomplete. For this sentence to work, we'd need to know the context of what was tested. It could *maybe* be an answer to a question, something like, `実験の結果はいつテストをしましたか？` But I'm told that's a little awkward.

In any case, if you wanted to say you had taken a test yesterday, and emphasize your participation, as opposed to the simple existence of the test (which is what your first example does), you would say something like `昨日、先生にテストされた`, which is, "yesterday, (I) was tested by my teacher."

Comment: Literal translation will NOT make things clear in this case.  That is because テストをした is said much more often by the teacher than by the student in the real Japanese-speaking world.

Comment: Wow, @TokyoNagoya, that is quite hostile comment. Is it really so bad that I offered a way of comparing the sentences by offering their English counterparts? That you can offer more insight with suggestions of who might say these sentences is fine, but the clarity of the comparison is up to the individual to decide. It would be more helpful to the site to be supportive with more information, not swatting down subtleties you don't like.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya, I actually appreciate it somewhat when you swat me down when what I say is wrong, but I think considering for the level of the asker's question, I don't think DaveMG errs with the level of explanation.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya I do not know any japanese.  But I disagree that a literal translation needs to fail to capture the implication.  How about "Yesterday, (I) performed [or executed] a test"?

Comment: There is actually a literal translation which works for テストする, but it is not the one given in this answer. Namely, "Yesterday, (I) tested (someone)." (昨日（人を）テストした。) -- that is to say, the **transitive** verb "to test" in English has similar semantics to テストする in Japanese. This is why you need to say "I **had** a test yesterday." (昨日テストがあった) or "I **was** tested (by someone) yesterday." (昨日（人に）テストされた。)

Comment: @virmaior: No one should ever "swat down" anyone's answer. We're all here to learn Japanese, not punish people for what they don't know. If there is something wrong with an answer, as with mine, then edits or comments should contain suggestions to improve them. That way, the both the person who asked the original question can learn that much more, and the person who suggested the partially incorrect answer can both learn, and everyone wins that much more.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie: Thanks for your explanation, but I'm actually still not clear on why `テストをしました` has to mean that the speaker tested someone else. I can see that `テストした`, which makes a verb of "test", and is therefor "tested", leans more to that meaning. In English "I tested..." seems incomplete and also implies acting a test on another. But in `テストをしました`, "test" is still a noun, meaning, "did *a* test", and as such, I can't see why a person couldn't say `昨日、僕がテストをした`. Unless in Japanese `テスト` as a noun carries implications that it does not have in English...?

Comment: @DaveMG Re "I tested..." feeling incomplete in English: as with all transitive verbs in Japanese, it's much easier to omit the object than it is in English, if it's already in context.

Comment: @DaveMG As for the semantics of テスト, I think the problem is that "test" has a number of meanings in English: "a series of questions" as well as "an evaluation of something" (as in "a test of his skills") -- テスト only has meaning similar to the latter. So when you say テストをする or テストする, it's closer to "he did an evaluation (of something)". This parallel is not perfect, but perhaps it helps a little.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, thanks for that. I still get thrown by 外来語 drawn from English words because I can't help but think of them in terms of what they mean to me in my native language. If the meaning in Japanese is more restricted to "an evaluation of something", then I can see how `昨日、僕がテストをした` is a little quirky.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, I've edited my answer to reflect what I've learned in the comments. Is what I say in my revision accurate enough?